# Graph theory problem for non-trivial graphs with n vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

I stumbled upon this question about graphs, and I am unable to think of a way to solve it.

This is a question: 
**Let G be a non-trivial graph containing at least one edge. Prove that, if  each two vertices of the same degree don't contain a common neighbor, that then G contains end vertex (vertex with degree 1).**

I am having trouble even starting, I need a proper way to think of how to solve these type of questions.

Comment: what does "contains end vertex" mean?

Comment: A vertex with degree 1 (leaf vertex).

Comment: I edited the question. The vertices must have the same degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the graph has no vertices of degree 1.

The graph has at least one edge, so it has a vertex $A_1$ of degree at least 2. The vertices joined to $A_1$ by an edge must all have different degrees, so at least one of them, say $A_2$, has degree at least 3.

We can now repeat this argument indefinitely. Having found a vertex $A_n$ with degree at least $n+1$, we know that the $\ge n+1$ neighbours of $A_n$ all have different degree and each of their degrees is at least 2. So one of them, $A_{n+1}$ must have degree at least $n+2$.

But the graph is assumed to be finite, so we have a contradiction. Hence there is a vertex of degree 1.

For completeness, we should show that it is possible to have a graph of $n$ vertices satisfying the condition. The easiest example is where there is just one edge.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there same general idea on how I should be solving these types of problems.

Comment: @lastSheep I cannot think of one. This is not a bookwork type question. But a good general rule is to look at simple cases first. I played with graphs of just a few points and soon realised that I kept being forced to add vertices with higher and higher degrees.